# Gradle - location for cached libraries in Windows

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

I am trying to develop a simple android application using Android Studio 3.1.1. While building I am getting a sync failed error from gradle. The bottom Build panel shows this error message.

> Could not HEAD
>   'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre8/1.2.0/kotlin-stdlib-jre8-1.2.0.pom'.
>   Received status code 503 from server: Service Unavailable Enable
>   Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

In my organization the access to this CDN is blocked. I tried by enabling the 'offline mode', now I am getting this error.

> No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.0
>   available for offline mode. Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync
>   project

I downloaded the file **kotlin-stdlib-jre8-1.2.0.pom**, but I don't know where to put it so that Gradle can use it (as a cached version).

Is there any way to make this work when the CDN site is not accessible?

Or anyone know the windows folder where the gradle stores the cached libs?

Answer (score 1):

Gradle supports an array of [repository types](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/repository_types.html). If you cannot use a Maven repository hosted by your organisation, there are other options available, like a flat directory repository or something else.

I would not recommend attempting to *trick* Gradle in believing it downloaded the dependencies. These are internal formats, subject to change from version to version.